# How do I execute functions one after the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe I'm using it wrong, but I want to chain 3 functions, with the second function starting when the first function completes and the third function starting when the second function completes. According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) I should be able to do it like this:

```
$.when( first() ).then( second() ).then(third() );
```

They all seem to be executing at the same time. What gives?

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XECY/2/)

I've also tried:

```
first().then( second() ).then(third() );
```

This will fade in the first div, but not the second and third;

Comment: Do you mean when the function completes, or the animation completes, because those are two very different things.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9XECY/4/

Comment: Sorry, I mean when the animation completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forcing the immediate execution of those functions. (By the way, they are not executing at the same time, but very quickly one after another, since JavaScript is single-threaded.)

You need to write `$.when(first).then(second).then(third)` (where first is a promise), and let the library execute them. not execute them yourself (which is what the parens do).

EDIT: Oh, didn't see the fiddle. Yeah, what SeanJohnson said.

Answer (score 1):

Just `first(); second(); third();` will work just fine. JavaScript is single-threaded.

The use of `when` and `then` is for things that integrate `Promise`, such as ajax requests (at least, that's my understanding as a non-jQuery-user)

EDIT: Here's your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XECY/3/) remade using CSS only, by the way ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do each function after animation completes [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9XECY/8/),

Use:

```
var first = function(callBack1, callBack2){
    $("#div1").fadeIn(2000, function(){callBack1(callBack2)});
}
var second = function(callBack){
  $("#div2").fadeIn(2000, callBack);

}

var third = function(){
  $("#div3").fadeIn(2000);

}


first(second, third);
```

Comment: He's using jQuery Deferreds to avoid the need for all of these callbacks.